# Finding points on $\vec r(t) = \vec At^3 + \vec Bt^2 + \vec Ct + \vec D$ where the tangent is parallel to the line $px + qy + k = 0$

Tags: calculus, geometry, curves, parametric, tangent-line

Given a line defined by the equation:
$$px + qy + k = 0$$
and a parametric cubic curve defined by:
$$\vec r(t) = \vec At^3 + \vec Bt^2 + \vec Ct + \vec D$$
where both curves lie in 2D space, how can I find all points on the cubic curve $t$ where the line is parallel to the tangent in these points?

Comment: Thats an arbitrary line, isn't it? You want the tangent lines as a function of $p$, $q$ and $k$? Why not just calculating the equation of the tangent line in an arbitrary point of the cubic by using its derivative, then transforming it to cartesian plane equation?

Comment: Calculate $r'(t)$, which gives the tangent vector to the cubic, and check for orthogonality with the line's normal vector, $n:=(p,q)$. (That is, solve $r'\cdot n = 0$.) This is gives you a quadratic in $t$, which is easily solved. Plug the candidate $t$-values back into $r(t)$ and check by substitution whether the corresponding points actually lie on the line.

Comment: @Blue Thanks, I wasn't to familiar with calculating the normal vector of the line like that. Is there perhaps somewhere I could read up more about that? Also, when you say check the candidate values, would both t values not necessarily lie on the line?

Comment: @GaryAllen: Just do a web search for "normal to line", I suppose. I'll say here that the  "normal form" of a line is $x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta=d$, where $(\sin\theta,\cos\theta)$ is the *unit-length* normal, and $d$ is the (signed) distance from the origin. So, in general, $px+qy=k$ has normal $(p,q)$ (of length $r=\sqrt{p^2+q^2}$) and distance-to-origin $k/r$. ... As for candidate $t$-values: the orthogonality of cubic-tangent and line-normal only accounts for *direction*, not *position*. It's possible (indeed, *likely*) that neither candidate $t$-value corresponds to a point on the line.

Comment: Ah okay thanks. And I don't think I need that condition as I indeed need my point to be on the curve and not on the line! Thanks @Blue

Comment: @GaryAllen: To be clear: If a solution point is on the curve but not on the given line, then that given line isn't a *tangent* at the point; it's only *parallel* to the tangent at the point. If that's all you need, then great ... but you should edit the question to say so.

Comment: Oops. I see what you mean. Yes - I indeed meant parallel @Blue

Comment: @GaryAllen: I have my own "Oops". In the normal form $x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta=d$, the unit-length normal is $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that $\vec r(t) = (x(t),y(t))$ and that the line

$$
p x + q y + k = 0
$$

can be written as $\vec r(t) = p_0 + \vec v t$ or $\cases{x = x_0 + v_x t\\ y = y_0 + v_y t}$ with the relationship between $p_0,\vec v, p, q, k$ which follows (assuming $v_x\ne 0$ and $v_y\ne 0$)

$$
\frac{x-x_0}{v_x}=\frac{y-y_0}{v_y}\Rightarrow v_y x- v_x y - x_0y_y+y_0 v_x = 0
$$

then $p = v_y, q = -v_x, k = - x_0y_y+y_0 v_x$

so we follow with $\vec r_1(t) = \vec At^3 + \vec Bt^2 + \vec Ct + \vec D$ and $\vec r_2(t) = p_0 + \vec v t$

Now the tangent vectors to $\vec r_1(t)$ are given by $\vec r_1'(t) = 3\vec At^2 + 2\vec Bt + \vec C$ and the tangent vectors to $r_2(t)$ are given by $\vec r_2'(t) = \vec v$. Finally if $\vec r_1'(t)$ and $\vec r_2'(t)$ are parallel then

$$
\vec r_1'(t) \times \vec r_2'(t) = \vec 0
$$

etc.